# Can I use a font I downloaded for free, commercially?

Tags: fonts, logo, font-licensing

I was looking for a font that I think I found on the WhatTheFont site (If it's not the same, it's very similar to Slate Pro Medium Italic). I found a few sites that offered a free download of this font, can I use it for commercial purposes then?

If I cannot find the very same font (or download it for free) is it OK to use  a slightly different one for a client who has a certain font in their logo? It's for a banner and for the headline I wanted to use the same font as in their logo.

Comment: *found a few sites that offered a free download of this font* - you can find all sorts of 'free' stuff on the internet, someone saying it's free/you being able to find it for free, does not make it free or legal to use. This goes for stuff beyond fonts, pay attention to what you use for commercial use and do your research.

Answer (score 3):

1: Slate Pro is not a free font and your client should be in possession of a commercial license if it is being used in their logo. If not, they would have to obtain a license for them to use it commercially.

https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/slate/pro-medium/

2: Try searching on www.dafont.com for a similar font, but be sure to check whether or not the font can be used commercially.

I have also used fonts that were not even close to those of my clients. As long as they work well, it should not be a problem. Unless your client insisted that you use that font.

Comment: The client doesn't necessarily need a license because their logo uses the font; whoever *created* the logo had to have had a license (and they need a license if it's being used elsewhere *as a font* or they need the actual font files in any way of course).